# slide down of jQuery in WordPress not works correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slidedown

I want to slide down some Divs in WordPress using jQuery slide down. but all item come over each other.
here is my code:

```
$(".more-button").click(function(){
  $("#feature-column").slideDown();
  slideFadeOut($('.more-button'));
});

$(".less-button").click(function(){
  $( "#feature-column" ).slideUp(2000);
  slideFadeIn($('.more-button'));
}); 
})
```

and div is some thing like this:

```
<div class="more-button"> show more </div>
    <div id="feature-column">
    <div>123</div>
    <div>123</div>
<div class="less-button"> show less</div>

    </div>
```

[image of wrong slide down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5bKr.png)

[image of correct slide down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IowJo.png)

Comment: Could you please link us to a real webpage? it's quite difficult to tell what's the problem. We would need to see the HTML structure + the CSS involved. Just basing the answer on your code i would say you might have a problem with id's. Since you are attaching the event to ALL the divs that have class .more-button or .less-button and you always go hit #feature-column (which being an ID should be UNIQUE)

Comment: @Diego https://datamoon.ir/jsj/

Comment: Ok, and what is exactly the desidered effect?

Comment: I want to slide down some icons but they shown wrongly as you can see in the image i attach

Comment: they should come below each other not on each other

Comment: @Diego when I click to slide down and them inspect the page everything is correct

Comment: @Diego I add pictures, you can see.